# Having a many-to-many association in the same model rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model called User and for my model, a user can either be a Leader or a Member. In my user model i have this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :username, :type
end
```

I thought i could create a many-to-many association in the User model like this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :username, :type

  has_and_belongs_to_many :users, :join_table => :team_members, :foreign_key => :team_leader_id
end
```

But i am not really sure how to go about it. So for example. 
User 1 - type :leader 
User 2 - type : member 
User 3 - type: member.

I want to create a relationship that can show that User 1 is the leader of  user 2 and user 3.

I am still a bit new to rails .

Comment: Do you have a `member` model and a `leader` model? If so its probably best to define them in those.

Answer (score 0):

well, you have `User` table and user can be member or leader,

- if you sure that there will not be any other roles

  - you can use `boolean` leader and can be true or false if false that mean this user is member
- if you not sure if there may be any other roles

  - you can go with what you currently being used `type` column and can contain `member` or `leader` that is for the first part.

then you need `leader` to control many `members` then there is 2 possibilites:

- Member can belongs to only 1 Leader then you will need to add a new column in user table called `leader_id` for example and in this case it will be

  ```
  has_many :members, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => :leader_id
  ```
- Member can belongs to many leaders then you will need to create many to many relation and then will use a new table that contain `leader_id` and `member_id` and both should be refer to user table as a forigen keys.

---

And better than all and have this relation in `User` model and its only valid for `Leader` you can have 2 models that inherit from `User` and that is called `STI` `Single Table Inheritance` you can read more about it [here](http://samurails.com/tutorial/single-table-inheritance-with-rails-4-part-1/):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # this type will be checked if Leader then its Leader model if Member then its Member model
  self.inheritance_column = 'type'
end


class Member < User
end

class Leader < User
  has_many :members, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => :leader_id
end
```

this model is away better than all, and in this case let's say in your User model you have:

```
1  User type='Member'
2  User type='Leaeder'
```

if you say:

```
 # will work      
 Member.find 1 
 User.find 1
 # will fail as type is not Leader
 Leader.find 1
```

Answer (score 0):

add leader_id to User

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :username, :type

  belongs_to :leader, class: User
  has_many :members, class: User, foreign_key: :leader_id
end
```

use :

```
@user_1 = User.create(name: "Jhon")
@user_2 = User.create(name: "Tom", leader: @user_1)

@user_1.members
```